# Weakly equal functions and its decomposition

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces, functional-inequalities, weak-topology

Suppose $f - g \in V$ where $V$ is a Hilbert space.
If $f, g \in V$ and 
$$
\langle f-g, v\rangle_V = 0, \forall v \in V^*,
$$
we say $f$ and $g$ are weakly equal in $V$.

I am wondering if there is a similar notion for the case where $f, g \not\in V$, but $f-g \in V$.
For example, let $V = H_0^1(U)$.
Consider $f \in H^1(U)$ whose trace is not zero.
Suppose there exists $g \in H^1(U)$ such that $T[g] = f|_{\partial U}$. 
Here $T$ is the trace operator. 
Then, $f-g$ is clearly in $H^1_0(U)$, however, $f, g \not\in H_0^1(U)$.
If $f-g$ is weakly equal to zero in $H_0^1(U)$, it seems that $f$ and $g$ are in some sense equal. However, I am not sure under what sense one can say that they are equal. 
I am very attempting to claim that $f$ and $g$ are weakly equal in $H^1(U)$.
However, since $H_0^1(U) \subset H^1(U)$, it is unclear whether it holds.

Any suggestions/comments/answers will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if $f - g \in V$ and
$$\langle f-g, v \rangle_V = 0$$
for all $v \in V^*$, then $f - g = 0$. This is a consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem and holds in arbitrary normed spaces.

Concerning your question: From the above, we see that $f - g = 0$ in $H_0^1(\Omega)$, in particular, $f = g$ a.e. Hence, $f$ and $g$ are the same (equivalence class of) function(s).

Comment: How did I miss that! Thanks!